# SSL Automatic Certificate Management status waiting

Tags: ssl, heroku

Upgraded to Hobby over 34hrs ago and enabled ACM Free SSL management. However in running `heroic certs:auto` The status of the SSL is marked as waiting. What does this mean? and how long does it take? It has been over 24hrs since install and enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helped me.

[Why is my domain stuck in the 'Waiting' state for ACM?](https://help.heroku.com/0S376M61/why-is-my-domain-stuck-in-the-waiting-state-for-acm)

Basically, Heroku uses Let's Encrypt to get SSL Certificates. Let's Encrypt limits how many certificates you can make per week. If you keep hitting "refresh" or if you keep enabling/disabling ACM, you'll end up making a bunch of certificates and you'll have to wait a week.

Thus, Heroku says NOT to enable/disable repeatedly to troubleshoot (which I did for an hour). Instead, try refreshing again (once) in two days. If it doesn't work within an hour, reach out to them.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded fairly recently from the free to the hobby plan. I recall them showing a message saying that it would take up to an hour to activate it. Mine worked in less than an hour. Hope that helps.